# Resque : How can I stop a job using Resque::Worker#new_kill_child?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

I am using resque and I have a worker processing a long job which I would like to stop, but the methods new_kill_child returns nil and the job doesn't stop.

```
2.0.0p247 :019 > worker1 = Resque::Worker.all.first
 => #<Worker Portable-Bureau:18811:high_priority,low_priority> 

2.0.0p247 :020 > worker1.job
 => {"queue"=>"high_priority", "run_at"=>"2013-10-15T15:20:33Z", "payload"=>{"class"=>"HighPriority", "args"=>[85]}} 

2.0.0p247 :021 > worker1.new_kill_child
 => nil
```

What should I do to terminate the job without killing the worker ?

Comment: did you read this blog post? http://engineering.hoteltonight.com/killing-stale-or-stuck-resque-jobs/

Comment: I can only find kill_child method in the documentation -> http://rubydoc.info/github/defunkt/resque/Resque/Worker. What does new_kill_child do?

Comment: new_kill_child does the same http://rdoc.info/gems/resque/Resque/Worker#new_kill_child-instance_method